# Aligning Image in react native to display top

Tags: reactjs, react-native, stylesheet

I have an image I am displaying in my react native application. I am quite new to it and I seem to have some difficulties in regards to styling an image the way I want. I am using the resizeMode of cover and it's displaying only the center of the image and the height is cropped, I would like to display the upper side of the image. below is a sample code of what I have at the moment.

```
                    <View style={styles.imageContentWrap}>
                      <Image
                        source={imageSource}
                        style={styles.imageStyle}
                      />
                    </View>
        imageContentWrap: {
          flexWrap: 'wrap',
          backgroundColor: 'green',
          flex: 0.58,
        },
        imageStyle: {
          flexWrap: 'wrap',
          width: '100%',
          height: '100%',
          resizeMode: 'cover',
          overflow: 'hidden',
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
resizeMode: 'contain',
```

or

```
<Image
                    source={imageSource}
                    resizeMode="contain"
                    style={styles.imageStyle}
                  />
```

Comment: If you are sure that the aspect ratio of your image is what you want, then you are searching for "contain" not "cover" try to add it in styles and see the results, try adding it as an attribute and see the results, they don't act the same for some reason

Comment: Aspect ratio? I have never used it before, how should I use it

Comment: If you have width: 375, and height: 375, this means your image should be squared, if the image is not squared, the green background will appear behind the image if you use "cover" resize mode, aspect ratio is the ratio between width and height, so for squared images the aspect ratio is 1:1, which means 1 to 1, which mean width to height is the same as 1 to 1, they are equal